# How to realize a dynamic sidebar with Django?

Tags: python, django

I plan on creating a sidebar with changing elements (depending on the current url and authentication-status).

For example: The default sidebar shows a login and a tag cloud.

- If a user is already logged in, I want to display a user menu.
- If the current url is `/tagcloud`, I want to hide it from the sidebar.

Actually, I need a way which enables me to do something like this in a view:

```
def some_view(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        sidebar.remove('login')
        sidebar.add('user_menu')

def tag_cloud(request):
    sidebar.remove('tag_cloud')
```

Afterwards, I want to pass the `sidebar` (implicitly, without passing it to `render_to_response`) to the template where I have in mind to do something like this:

```
<div id="sidebar">
    {{ sidebar }}
</div>
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'd better do this in a context_processors.py file
That also mean you have to [use a RequestContext when returning your views](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#render-to-response)

```
def include_tagcloud(request):
    if request.path == '/tagcould/':
        tagcloud = Tags.objects.filter(active=True) #whatever 
    return {'tagcloud': tagcloud}

def include_login(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        loginform = MyLoginForm(request.POST) 
        #passing a Django form + POST data in the case of re-submit
    return {'loginform' : loginform}
```

And then in your template :

```
{% if loginform %}
      <form action="accounts/login/">
      {{form.as_p}}
      <input type="submit" name="Login">
      </form>
{% endif %}

{% if tagcloud %}
       {%for tag in tagcloud %}.....{%for}
{% endif %}
```

In this example the login form points to a fixed view,
if you want to catch the login form post on everyview, I don't know how to do

EDIT : if you don't use the CSRF features of Django, you could simply insert the login form in the base template without using any django form and pointing to a login view :

```
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
    <form action="accounts/login/">
    <input type="text" name="username"><input type="password" name="password">
    <input type="submit" name="Login">
    </form>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! That's the solution I was looking for. According to the documentation (http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#writing-your-own-context-processors) a context processor has to return a dict - and it works fine. Thank you.

Comment: You can also stick the sidebar in a separate template, and include that. Makes for easy reuse.

Comment: @matthew : but in this case, you have to include a tagcloud in every context of every view, the context_processor can save you db hits here.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, but you can use inheritance of templates as well as composition. Then include your sidebar in a parent template that is used/inherited from in all of your templates. Then it is easy to find the template for the sidebar: it's in a separate file.

Comment: you're right, but I just use templates to display something, I don't want them handle this kind of logic... lot of ways to do this ...

Answer (score 0):

Answer of [@Dominique](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4693498/254553) is correct but When you write something in `context_processors` that's load at any page of the website. That maybe makes a performance issue.

I think the right way to handle dynamic sidebar is `simpletag` and use where you need.

```
def get_sidebar():
    tags = Tags.objects.filter(active=True)
    latest_posts = Post.objects.all().order_by('-create_at')[:10]

    html = render_to_string("sidebar.html", {
        "tags": tags,
        "latest_posts": latest_posts
        })

    return html
```

And now just use in template files:

```
<div class="col-md-4 sidebar">
    {% get_sidebar %}
</div>
```

Also, you can pass `request` to `simpletag` to use `user.is_authenticated` for authenticated user access.